# jquery top tweets plugin similar to this

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

ive been doing some searching and have failed to find a plugin similar to this. I know this may not be a valid question but please help lower the frustration. post me links of plugins similar or better. http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/twitter-like-topwtweets/

The plugin will be used to show the latest updates from my website. so im not looking for a twitter plugin. It should have the slide and fade effect like in the link

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/jquery-twitter-plugin-update-jtwitter.html